# NotSerializableException: java.io.FileInputStream

Tags: java, rmi

My app is throwing this error:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.FileInputStream
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:194)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:209)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.getEntityBlob(Unknown Source)
    at com.mycompany.backend.repository.EntityRepositoryImpl.getEntityBlob(EntityRepositoryImpl.java:260)
```

The "client" side of the RMI method is this:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
EntityRepository repository =
    (EntityRepository) registry.lookup(EntityRepository.class.getName());
return repository.getEntityBlob(appId, namespace, entityType, entityId, blobKey);
```

And the "server" side is this

```
  public InputStream getEntityBlob(
      String appId,
      String namespace,
      String entityType,
      final String entityId,
      final String blobKey) throws RemoteException {
    final InputStream[] inputStream = new InputStream[1];
    manager.transactPersistentEntityStore(xodusRoot, appId, true, txn -> {
      EntityId idOfEntity = txn.toEntityId(entityId);
      final Entity entity = txn.getEntity(idOfEntity);
      inputStream[0] = entity.getBlob(blobKey);
    });
    return inputStream[0];
  }
```

Does it mean that `FileInputStream` cannot work with RMI? Or it should work and there's just a problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to transmit an `InputStream` over RMI

See: [Strategy to transmit a stream over RMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147697/strategy-to-transmit-a-stream-over-rmi)